# Pandas: Find max value in column and print its row

Tags: python, pandas, max, dataframe

I need find max value in column `xrb` and print this row (`datetime`, `xra`, max of (`xrb`).

Here is my `df` data:

```
                datetime           xra           xrb
1020 2016-02-21 17:00:00  1.000000e-09  2.380000e-07
1020 2016-02-21 17:00:01  1.000000e-09  2.380000e-07
1020 2016-02-21 17:00:02  1.000000e-09  2.380000e-07
1021 2016-02-21 17:01:00  1.080000e-09  2.370000e-07
1022 2016-02-21 17:02:00  1.000000e-09  2.350000e-07
1023 2016-02-21 17:03:00  1.000000e-09  2.340000e-07
1024 2016-02-21 17:04:00  1.000000e-09  2.330000e-07
1025 2016-02-21 17:05:00  1.000000e-09  2.330000e-07
```

I used this code:

```
print list(df.loc[df['xrb'].idxmax()])
```

But I get only list `['datetime','xra','xrb']`

Any suggestion?

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: Hello man...I need list of row where is datetime , xra and maximum of xrb from whole column...it can be many same maximum in column xrb and I need last maximum

Comment: Maybe you can try `print list(df.loc[df['xrb'][::-1].idxmax()])`

Comment: The same ...I get only  ['datetime', 'xra', 'xrb']  but no values

Comment: Problem is in duplicity in your index.

Comment: I see...And how can I move it?

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. Your code does not run. I used made up values for the undefined variables and wasn't able to replicate the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try [`idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.idxmax.html) of inverted `df` by `[::-1]`:

```
print df
                datetime           xra           xrb
1018 2016-02-21 17:00:00  1.000000e-09  2.380000e-07
1019 2016-02-21 17:00:01  1.000000e-09  2.380000e-07
1020 2016-02-21 17:00:02  1.000000e-09  2.380000e-07
1021 2016-02-21 17:01:00  1.080000e-09  2.370000e-07
1022 2016-02-21 17:02:00  1.000000e-09  2.350000e-07
1023 2016-02-21 17:03:00  1.000000e-09  2.340000e-07
1024 2016-02-21 17:04:00  1.000000e-09  2.330000e-07


print list(df.loc[df['xrb'][::-1].idxmax()])
[Timestamp('2016-02-21 17:00:02'), 1.0000000000000001e-09, 2.3800000000000001e-07]
```

EDIT:

If you have duplicity index, try find all rows:

```
print df
                datetime           xra           xrb
1020 2016-02-21 17:00:00  1.000000e-09  2.380000e-07
1020 2016-02-21 17:00:01  1.000000e-09  2.380000e-07
1020 2016-02-21 17:00:02  1.000000e-09  2.380000e-07
1021 2016-02-21 17:01:00  1.080000e-09  2.370000e-07
1022 2016-02-21 17:02:00  1.000000e-09  2.350000e-07
1023 2016-02-21 17:03:00  1.000000e-09  2.340000e-07
1024 2016-02-21 17:04:00  1.000000e-09  2.330000e-07

print df[df['xrb'] == df['xrb'].max()]
                datetime           xra           xrb
1020 2016-02-21 17:00:00  1.000000e-09  2.380000e-07
1020 2016-02-21 17:00:01  1.000000e-09  2.380000e-07
1020 2016-02-21 17:00:02  1.000000e-09  2.380000e-07
```

Comment: And How I find last maximum?

Comment: I have it print df[df['xrb'] == df['xrb'][::-1].max()]

Comment: I have next problem...I dont know how I get this to list...print list(df[df['xrb'] == df['xrb'].max()]) show  ['datetime', 'xra', 'xrb'] again.

Comment: First I check last max - for me work `print df[df['xrb'] == df['xrb'].max()][::-1].reset_index(drop=True).ix[0,:]` and if you need `list`, try `print df[df['xrb'] == df['xrb'].max()][::-1].reset_index(drop=True).ix[0,:].tolist()`

Comment: Aha koukal jsem ze jsi z bratislavy...muzeme po nasem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104290/discussion-between-jezrael-and-franta-konopnik).